# Get Data Last Year From This Month SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a year & month in my database tables seperate column.(like Year 2017 , Month 8) I need to filter that data for I need past year data from today. I want 13 months of data to be returned.

> > If today is 13/8/2018 and i need data From 8/2017 to 8/2018 only.

I tried it like this,

```
SELECT Year,Month,News
FROM TBL_NEWS
WHERE Year >= cast(datepart(yyyy,DATEADD(yyyy,-1,getdate()))
```

Comment: So you want data from 1st Aug 2017 to 31st Aug 2018?

Comment: @mjwills Exactly yes.

Answer (score 2):

You have split the date into two columns.  That can be tricky.  Here is one method for 12 months of data:

```
where datefromparts(year, month, 1) >= datefromparts(year(getdate()) - 1, month(getdate()), 1) and
      datefromparts(year, month, 1) < datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)
```

If you actually want 13 months of data, change the `<` to `<=`.